# Integrating Mediapipe into iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mediapipe

**Problem:** After building Mediapipe and playing around with their example iOS apps I was surprised to see that I could not find any comprehensive materials out there from which you can learn how to take their Machine Learning frameworks and further integrate them into a custom iOS app.

**Question:** Am I missing something? Can somebody provide some insight into integrating their ML solutions in an iOS app in order for the output to be further used in a custom use case in Swift?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @enigrify No, I've dropped it for the moment and went for a workaround in Vision Framework.

Comment: I'm still baffled that nobody can provide a decent material on integrating a framework that has been around for years with a targeted platform. The amount of indifference from Google is also truly amazing.

Comment: are you able to run using https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/ios

Comment: I am not able to setup and run Mediapipe iOS examples if you have setup kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I know the struggle. We've been using MediaPipe for some of the apps we built and had to do a lot of work to make it work. Because of this we've built an SDK for Pose Estimation using MediaPipe that makes it faster to integrate in. It's called [QuickPose.ai](https://quickpose.ai) & here's our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/quickpose/quickpose-ios-sdk).

It might not be what you're looking for if you're looking for Object Detection or some of the other features of MediaPipe. Would love to know what you were trying to do with MediaPipe and iOS?

Disclosure: I'm the co-founder of QuickPose

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34434911)